# Loading scripts with require.js

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs

Here is my require.js load file:

```
require.config({
    urlArgs: "noCache=" + (new Date).getTime(),
    paths: {
        jquery: "vendor/jquery-1.8.2.min",
        bootstrap: "vendor/bootstrap.min",      
        underscore: "vendor/underscore-min",
        backbone: "vendor/backbone-min",    
        template: "libs/template"    
    }
});

require(["jquery", "bootstrap", "underscore", "backbone", "template", "main"], 
function ($, bootstrap, underscore, backbone, template, main) {
```

})

And inside the main.js file I have the following code:

```
define(["jquery", "underscore", "backbone"], function ($, _, Backbone) {
  //Backbone and _ are undefined here, why?
})
```

So why ,,_" and ,,Backbone" are undefined here, what am I doing wrong?
How to properly use them inside other files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are new to backbone and require js integration take a look to the following tutorial:

http://backbonetutorials.com/organizing-backbone-using-modules/

You are probably using the non-AMD version of Backbone and underscore. Using shim config you can load any library, even non-AMD modules, here is a shim config snippet from one of my source files:

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: 'assets/js/',
    paths : {
        'jquery': 'lib/jquery/jquery.min',
        'underscore': 'lib/underscore/underscore-amd-min',
        'backbone': 'lib/backbone/backbone-amd-min',
        'bootstrap': 'lib/bootstrap/bootstrap.min',
    },
    shim: {
        'backbone': {
            deps: ['jquery', 'underscore'],
            exports: 'Backbone'
        },
        'underscore': {
            exports: '_'
        },
        'bootstrap': {
            deps: ['jquery']
        }
    }
});
```

---

An alternative solution would be using the AMD version of those libraries you will find them here:
https://github.com/amdjs

Download and point to them in your `path` section.

Comment: Yeah... i am new to these two, especially require.js (I am just trying to integrate it for the first time). Thanks for the great articles, but can you please be more specific about what needs changing here?

Comment: Sure, you have to download the amd supported versions for underscore (https://github.com/amdjs/backbone) and backbone (https://github.com/amdjs/backbone) and include those libraries instead of the current ones.

Comment: @hjuster I just looked at my source files and realized that I'm also using the none-AMD versions of those libraries. This is possible with shim config. I edited my answer and included an example of shim config.